# IOS9 and uiwebview issues?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, ios9

I have webview working fine for version less then ios9, but seems not working for ios9, and its shows me a blank page, but the url is passed.

Comment: its working fine.but taking time to open web page. once update your code .

Comment: In iOS 9 apple made it, by default, refuse all connections not using TLS 1.2. Most likely this is your issue. You should read the iOS 9 release notes and investigate this. If its possible to upgrade the server (if its under your control)

Comment: @Uma mine its not even opening after waiting a long time.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin i'll read the notes then.

Comment: @M.Almeida check by replacing weburl

Comment: @Uma Already did it, not working

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView  loadRequest:req];

Comment: URL is updated , but its still blank

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the order of updating url and rendering page. In ios9, url will not be changed immediately, even if you directly assign value to it.

So you can try to set a timeout to wait until url updated.

```
updateUrl();
window.setTimeout(function(){
    renderPage();
},30);
```

sometimes set timeout to 0 would do the trick, because it forces the code runs in the next event loop.