# Blank screen in UIWebview

Tags: ios, xamarin, ios10

```
string url = "https://www.google.com"
webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
```

I've tried in both xcode and xamarin, this code still working for IOS9 device and IOS10 simulator. But when I try on a real ios10 device getting a blanks screen.

Are there any changes about security rules in IOS 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement `didFailLoadWithError` from the UIWebView delegate and see if that helps you anything. See the [UIWebView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617970-webview) for further information.

Comment: thanks for helpful answer, I solved my problem, it's beacuse of tls version of server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967264/ios9-and-uiwebview-issues